# How to insert multiple rows using standalone procedure in dbviz

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert, procedure, dbvisualizer

I want to fetch data from student and teacher tables and insert into another table. but when I try to do that I am getting below error

```
@delimiter %%%;
BEGIN
 DECLARE name CHAR (3);
 DECLARE subject VARCHAR(25);
 DECLARE ID DECIMAL(19,0);
 DECLARE teacher_name VARCHAR(25);          
 
 insert into temp_table(std_name, subject, std_id, teacher_name) values (
SELECT std.name, std.subject, std.ID, tr.teacher_name FROM Student std inner join teacher tr on std.subject = tr.subject); 

 END%%%
    @delimiter ;
%%%
```

Result

[Code: -811, SQL State: 21000]  The result of a scalar fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more than one row.. SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, DRIVER=4.22.29

Comment: The syntax is `INSERT INTO t (c1, c2, c3) SELECT ...`. I.e. no VALUES, no parentheses.

Comment: [Code: -803, SQL State: 23505]  One or more values in the INSERT statement, UPDATE statement, or foreign key update caused by a DELETE statement are not valid because the primary key, unique constraint or unique index identified by "1" constrains table "temp-table" from having duplicate values for the index key.. SQLCODE=-803, SQLSTATE=23505, DRIVER=4.22.29